# How to erase changes I made to a specific folder after pushing up to Github

Tags: git

So here's the issue, I made a whole slew of changes to a Rails app in the `app/views` folder and I pushed up the changes. I could look at the Github UI and revert these changes back line by line, but there must be an easier way. These changes were made 2 commits ago. Is there a way to change the contents of everything in the `app/views` folder back to their state 2 commits ago and then push up/overwrite those changes up on Github. What's the best way to do this?

IN theory, this seems to be close but I know these commands reset my entire app... which is not what I want. I only want to reset a certain folder:

```
git checkout <branch-name>
git reset --hard <commit that I want>
git push -f origin <branch-name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is

```
git checkout <branch-name>
git checkout <commit that you want> -- folder/that/you/want
git add folder/that/you/want
git commit -m "revert bad changes"
git push origin
```

This should be done with a clean workspace, at least within `folder/that/you/want`

Answer (score 0):

Use `git rebase -i`, change every line to `edit`, then use `git checkout goodcommit dirtoreset`.